# Syntax error (comma) in query expression. MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm building a sql query in Access 2013. This is my query:

```
SELECT  
COUNT(Age) FROM Members AS [Under 12] WHERE Age <= 12,
COUNT(Age) FROM Members AS [13-18] WHERE Age BETWEEN 13 AND 18
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'Age <= 12, 
>    COUNT(Age) FROM SukkotMembers AS [13-18] WHERE Age BETWEEN 13 AND 18`

The problem is with the comma at the end of line two, but I can't see why. When I run just one line it works fine. I am really new to SQL Just so you are aware.

Also I just realized that the `AS [Under 12]` and `AS [13-18]` are not working and I also have no idea why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also sum:

```
SELECT  
    Sum(Abs(Age <= 12)) AS [Under 12],
    Sum(Abs(Age BETWEEN 13 AND 18)) AS [13-18]  
FROM 
    Members
```

Comment: That is quite elegant!

Comment: Thanks! short and sweet

Answer (score 4):

First: the syntax you are using is not valid SQL as you have more than one `FROM` clause which is not allowed; the same applies to the `where` clause, which by the way operates on the whole set.

You can't just take bits and pieces of SQL and patch together to get a working query - there is a rather strict and well-defined syntax that you must adhere to.

What you want is either to use subqueries that return scalar values or to use conditional counting:

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(IIF(Age<=12,age,null)) AS [Under 12] 
 ,COUNT(IIF(Age BETWEEN 13 AND 18,age,null)) AS [13-18]  
FROM Members
```

Also, `FROM Members AS [13-18]` assigns an alias to the table, not a column.

Using subqueries (which I guess might have been your intent):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEMBERS WHERE AGE<=12) AS  [UNDER 12] ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEMBERS WHERE AGE BETWEEN 13 AND 18) AS  [13-18]
FROM MEMBERS
```

Comment: thanks jpw both of you examples work. I went with Gustav's because it was shortest

Comment: and thank you for letting me know where i went wrong